# Genymotion dose not start with API 21

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-5.0-lollipop, genymotion

I have install latest genymotion in my PC. Its works grate with API 18 and 19 but when I try to start Genymotion emulator with API 21 it doesn't work. Show black screen with "**android**" forever.

[image]

Comment: Wait some more...I'm **extremely new** to droid dev, and one thing I have learned so far at my baby n00b stage, is that emulators are pretty much, well, horrible. GenyMotion is _better_ but it's _relative_ - so "forever" is same (I'm on an "old" Mac Pro circa 2008).

Answer (score 0):

Wait for some time to load. It purely depends on system configration like RAM,os,Chipset,Processor

Update the ADT plugin too. Re start ADB.
*if you are using adb for any other IDEs like eclipse then close it.

Answer (score 0):

- you have to start virtual machine manually from virtualbox.
- try again to start genymotion like this

[image]

It works for me. Hope it help's you.

Answer (score 0):

It was 2014-2015, but the problem with 5.* ver. (21, 22 API) is still here

4.* and even 6 (23 API) works great, but 5.* won't start at all

So it can be considered like Genymotion fail/fault